# Web torrent client that supports monthly traffic limit

Tags: linux, bittorrent, traffic

I am looking for a torrent client that offers a web interface, and also can limit the monthly ingoing and outgoing traffic. For example, only allowing a set limit of 250GB combined in/outgoing traffic per month. Once this limit has been met, traffic is blocked (or another process is trigged) and a page is displayed starting the limit has been met.

I am currently using Debian Lenny, but I can rebuilt to others.

Comment: It would help noting clearly that you do not want a linear shaping over the month but a hard limit that will block torrent traffic at 250GB per month.

Comment: Sounds to me like a SuperUser question.

Answer (score 3):

I've gotta say that I've been very happy the last couple of years using [torrentflux-b4rt](http://tf-b4rt.berlios.de/home.html) as my primary torrent client.

And although it doesn't naturally include the monthly transfer limit. However the forum does include a hack on how to add that feature to the program. Which is [here](http://tf-b4rt.berlios.de/forum/index.php/topic,1794.0.html).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a client since have not looked at many.

But, since you are on linux, you could setup a iptables meter on the torrent traffic and script a firewall action after your threshold crossover.

Note that I am not referring to [the limiting/shaping control](https://serverfault.com/questions/52027/how-can-i-limit-per-user-bandwidth).
But, a slightly more involved trick using **`iptables`**, **`cronjob`** and some **scripting**.

1. Setup [metering of the torrent activity with `iptables`](http://wiki.openvz.org/Traffic_accounting_with_iptables)

   - This would be where you need some help from others,
     I have not used iptables as extensively as this would require.
     Maybe, the `Owner Match` with `--uid-owner` option will work (limited to OUTPUT chains).
   - If you get this worked out, the other parts should be easy to setup
   - Setup a `cronjob` to track the meter (basic scripting)
   - When the threshold (250GB) is hit,
   - introduce [a `iptables` rule to block torrents](https://serverfault.com/questions/27088/using-linux-iptables-how-to-block-torrents-or-any-p2p-protocols)
   - alternatively, shutdown the torrent client itself
   - at the end of your period (month)
   - check if the firewall was activated

     - disable it if so (or restart the client maybe)
   - reset the meters with a `-Z` command

---

I have conjured this method just now.
Do not have sufficient data to confirm it will work.
Maybe, some others with more iptables experience will be able validate and add.

Or, there could be an easier way to do this -- with some other tool chain.

Will update further if I get any more ideas.

Comment: That sounds like it would work. I could use --uid-owner with the iptables because the torrent client has it's own system user. Would you be able to show me how to set this up? I can give you my email address if it is easier! 
Thank you.

Comment: Well, this is roughly the same that I've suggested you in my answer[1] to your previous question. I think that using the --quota option would be a lot easier. But of course YMMV and you should experiment with different solutions until you reach the one that works best for you. Best regards, Alex. [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/52027/how-can-i-limit-per-user-bandwidth/52229#52229

Comment: I think the setting up of metering is the difficult part, so I can track the traffic, I will try and look through it though. Thank you for the help so far.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a torrent application out there that's web-based and automatically limits bandwidth per month.  There is, however, web-based torrent clients that limits bandwidth per torrent (ie. utorrent).

You may need to do that by monitoring the incoming traffic because all of the torrent clients I know of, only do the limiting bandwidth per torrent.

Answer (score 0):

I'll check this and edit when I get home, but I'd take a look at [deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/).

Comment: Unless you have a specific plugin I'm not aware of, no, it can't